# describing a class as method parameter in typescript

Tags: typescript

I wish to describe a method parameter that contains a class that extends a superclass. I did it in that way:

```
class SuperClass {
  public superMethod() {}
}

class JustAnotherClass extends SuperClass {
  constructor(){ super() }
}

class SomeClassCollection {
  private myClasses : Array<any> = [];

  public addClass<T extends SuperClass>(newClass : T){
    this.myClasses.push(newClass);
  }
}

let collection = new SomeClassCollection();
collection.addClass(JustAnotherClass)
```

But now I get the following error:
**"Argument of type 'typeof JustAnotherClass' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SuperClass'.
  Property 'superMethod' is missing in type 'typeof JustAnotherClass'."**

Can somebody explain me what I did wrong?

Comment: That should be `T extends typeof SuperClass`, if you want the argument to be a class extending `SuperClass` rather than an instance of such a class. Alternatively change the *use* of `T`: `newClass: new() => T`.

Comment: Thank you very much! "T extends typeof SuperClass" is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass a class type or an instance?

Below are examples of the two cases.

```
class SuperClass {
  public superMethod() {}
}

class JustAnotherClass extends SuperClass {
  constructor(){ super() }
}

class SomeClassCollection {
  private myClasses : Array<any> = [];

  public addClass<T extends SuperClass>(newClass : T){
    this.myClasses.push(newClass);
    }

  public addClassType(newClass : typeof SuperClass){
    this.myClasses.push(newClass);
  }
}

let collection = new SomeClassCollection();
collection.addClass(new JustAnotherClass());
collection.addClassType(JustAnotherClass);
```